# Best Asymptotic Complexity for Persistent Union Find

Tags: ds.data-structures, time-complexity, functional-programming

In this paper https://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/puf-wml07.pdf, they claim to have a practically fast persistent union-find data structure for most use-cases, but it's still not polylogarithmic in the worst case (the worst case being, I have two variants which I alternately update between); only in a backtracking search.

Are there any implementations of a persistent union find datastructure which guarantee amortized polylogarithmic time complexity per operation regardless of how it's used?

Comment: I don't care if the constant overhead or the exponent on the log is so large that it's impractical

Comment: Doesn't using union by rank (without path compression) together with the fat node technique automatically give you this?

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I guess you're right.  I always assumed path compression was necessary for an efficient union-find data structure.  It didn't even occur to me that union by rank might be sufficient.